# Ratios with Datatable

Tags: c#

I have an application that I am making an have run into a place where I got stuck. My problem is this: how can I create a ratio with a datatable.

Ex:
My Table:

---

|gh | gh | tf | tf|

---

|tf | tf | tf | tf|

---

|gh | gh | tf | tf|

---

My output:

4 gh:8 tf

Anything could be in the table, so I was hoping to use Linq to determine the ratio .. but didnt know how to find out all the diffrent results in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
private Dictionary<String, Int32> GetCounts(DataTable dt)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var v in row.ItemArray)
        {
            string key = (v ?? string.Empty).ToString();

            if (!result.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                result.Add(key, 0);
            }

            result[key]++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```